# Can someone clarify what is Homebrew in cppcheck on Mac OSX installation

Tags: cppcheck

I have found a [page](http://macappstore.org/cppcheck/) which has steps to instal cppcheck on Mac OSX, but it is not clear  what are we doing with 2nd step

1. Press Command+Space and type Terminal and press enter/return key.
2. Run in Terminal app:
   ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)" < /dev/null 2> /dev/null
   and press enter/return key. Wait for the command to finish.
3. brew install cppcheck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homebrew helps you install packages (software).

You need to install it in order to use it; that is what step 2 is doing, installing Homebrew.

Then, you can use homebrew commands to install available packages, like the one you have in step 3 (cppcheck).